# AngularJS: ng-disabled passing more than 1 expression?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Does anyone know if its possible to have ng-disabled use 2 expressions. I would like to disable the buttton when its clicked, this is to stop DOUBLE POSTBACK but i would also like it disabled until the form is valid i.e.

```
  <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" ...............
```

But what about double postback.

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
ng-disabled="condition1 || condition2"
```

condition1 would be your validation and the contition2 would be when the button has been clicked. Setting either to true will disable the button.

Comment: Great thanks, I suppose you can't send it directly to a method on the scope can you as this means it would be calling the method all the time ??  So this would be the recommended way of doing it ?

Comment: Do you mean the scope on your controller? If you have a submit method, you could set a variable inside of it when you handle the the submit. For the validation you can still use !myForm.$valid.